# Having problems splitting a long string with preg_match_all

Tags: php, regex

I have a variable (text) and it is updated with sentences every time there is an update. When i display this array it turns into 1 long sentence, and i want to break this up in single sentences for readability.

```
<?php
$pattern = '~\\d+-\\d+-\\d{4} // \\w+: ~ ';
$subject = '01-02-2015 // john: info text goes here 10-12-2015 // peter: some more info

';
$matches = array();
$result = preg_match_all ($pattern, $subject, $matches);
?>
```

Which gives this output:

```
$matches:

array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => '01-02-2015 // john: ',
    1 => '10-12-2015 // peter: ',
  ),
)
```

I'd like the output to be:

```
$matches:

array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => '01-02-2015 // john: info text goes here',
    1 => '10-12-2015 // peter: some more info',
  ),
)
```

I need the output to be like this so i can use a foreach loop to print each sentence.

ps. I'd like to try to get it to work this way first, because otherwise i'd need to change a lot of entries in the database.

pps. I'm also not a hero with regex as you can see, so i hope someone can help me out!

Comment: This should work `$pattern = '~\d+-\d+-\d{4} // \w+: [a-zA-Z ]+~';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change your regex like below,

```
$pattern = '~\d+-\d+-\d{4} // \w+: .*?(?=\s\d+|$)~';
```

`.*?` will do a non-greedy match of zero or more characters until a space followed by digits or end of the line is reached.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/zY2sZ5/4)

```
$str = "01-02-2015 // john: info text goes here 10-12-2015 // peter: some more info";
preg_match_all('~\d+-\d+-\d{4} // \w+: .*?(?=\s\d+|$)~', $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 01-02-2015 // john: info text goes here
            [1] => 10-12-2015 // peter: some more info
        )

)
```

Comment: Why aren't I'm surprised that you are on this question :D

Comment: Ah, that makes sense, i couldn't get the part last part to work.